# Geofencing in Background odd

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, geolocation

I'm working on a geofence function for an application with the following design pattern

GoefenceManager

- singleton to handle region monitoring register
- location manager delegate

Everything is working fine up to didEnterRegion delegate method. Here is the implementation in place in that delegate :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    NSLog(@"#Entered Region - %@", region.identifier);

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
        {
            __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;

            background_task = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{


                                   if (background_task != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
                {
                    NSLog(@"#Entered Region - Background task ended");

                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: background_task];
                    background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                }

            }];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


                // Call a third party API to publish the enter region event

#ifdef GOEFENCE_DEBUG

                UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

                if (notification == nil) return;

                notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You entered region > %@", region.identifier];
                notification.alertAction = @"My functionnal service name";
                notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
                [notification release];

#endif

                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:background_task];
                background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see nothing fancy when the delegate method fire:

1. Log into console
2. Start a background task
3. Start a finite lenght task
4. Call a webservice
5. Show a local notification

When i run this on the simulator any time the didEnterRegion is called everything is working as expected, application running AND in background

But running on a device only the local notification is shown. I write logs into a file when application is running on device in debug mode. But neither the NSLog(@"#Entered Region - %@", region.identifier); nor NSLog(@"#Entered Region - Background task ended"); is written. Webservice is never called. BUT local notification is shown.

Anyone could help because i can't see what part i'm missing.
Thanks